# Python: In a dataframe, create a new column with a string sliced from a column with the value of another column

Tags: python, pandas, slice

I have a pretty simple problem that i can't get around.

I create a dataframe and i would like to generate a new column with a sliced string from one column with a slice value from another column.

Ex:
From this:

```
dftest = pd.DataFrame({'string' : ['EXAMPLE']*5, 'position' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

   position   string
0         1  EXAMPLE
1         2  EXAMPLE
2         3  EXAMPLE
3         4  EXAMPLE
4         5  EXAMPLE
5         1  OTHER
6         2  OTHER
7         3  OTHER
```

I want this:

```
   position   string    new
0         1  EXAMPLE  E
1         2  EXAMPLE  EX
2         3  EXAMPLE  EXA
3         4  EXAMPLE  EXAM
4         5  EXAMPLE  EXAMP
5         1  OTHER    O
6         2  OTHER    OT
7         3  OTHER    OTH
```

I tried:

```
dftest['new'] = dftest.string.str[:dftest.position]
dftest['new'] = dftest.string.str[:dftest['position']]
dftest['new'] = dftest.string[:dftest.position]
```

as well as different row iteration methods but each time I end up with Nan values.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `iterrows` method:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[i, 'new'] = row['string'][:row['position']]
```

Example:

```
In [60]: dftest
Out[60]:
   position   string
0         1  EXAMPLE
1         2  EXAMPLE
2         3  EXAMPLE
3         4  EXAMPLE
4         5  EXAMPLE
5         1    OTHER
6         2    OTHER
7         3    OTHER

for i, row in dftest.iterrows():
    dftest.loc[i, 'new'] = row['string'][:row['position']]


In [62]: dftest
Out[62]:
   position   string    new
0         1  EXAMPLE      E
1         2  EXAMPLE     EX
2         3  EXAMPLE    EXA
3         4  EXAMPLE   EXAM
4         5  EXAMPLE  EXAMP
5         1    OTHER      O
6         2    OTHER     OT
7         3    OTHER    OTH
```

**EDIT**

Or you could use `apply` which is more convenient:

```
dftest.apply(lambda x: x['string'][:x['position']], axis=1)
```

Comment: In my dataframe I got Error when i try:
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method

Comment: @Jérémz probably your numbers in `position` column are strings. Could you check `dtype` of that column with `dftest.position.dtype`?

Comment: You need to convert it to `float` or `int` with `dftest.position = dftest.position.astype(float)` or use `dftest.position = pd.to_numeric(dftest.position)`

Comment: Thanks, now my column return dtype('float64')
But I still get
TypeError: ('slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method', u'occurred at index 0')

Comment: @Jérémz hmm.., could you post `dftest.dtypes`. But anyway with `dftest.position` apply should work...

Comment: I got:
position  float64
string    object
dtype: object

Comment: Did you check that with your `dftest` which you attach to the question?

Comment: No, i'm actually working on a dataframe which is much bigger with 878 rows and 11 columns, so i made this example to not make the topic too heavy
but the structure and the dtype are actually the same as in the example
both are <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> and should react the same way

Comment: I changed to values in 'position' to integer and now it's working
It was just that it couldn't accept the float when slicing
Thanks for the help

Comment: @Jérémz yeah, sorry for the confusion. Of course indices should be integers and you need to do `astype(int)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following

```
dftest['new'] = [dftest.iloc[i]['string'][0:dftest.iloc[i]['position']] for i in range(0,len(dftest))]
```

This will check the position.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that it's a good idea but it is not working in my particular case, i really need to refer to the value in column 'position' as there is multiple strings in 'string' and the values in 'position' can change or reload.
I will modify my example to make it more clear

Answer (score 1):

One method is to enumerate the string using a list comprehension.

```
dftest['new'] = [s[:n] for s, n in zip(dftest.string, dftest.position)]

>>> dftest
   position   string    new
0         1  EXAMPLE      E
1         2  EXAMPLE     EX
2         3  EXAMPLE    EXA
3         4  EXAMPLE   EXAM
4         5  EXAMPLE  EXAMP
5         1    OTHER      O
6         2    OTHER     OT
7         3    OTHER    OTH
```

Comment: Thanks, the same as with Anton's answer
my dtype for position is now float64 and the dataframe is a 
class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'
but i get :
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method

Comment: I believe that means that position contains values other than integers or None.  Try dftest.position.unique() to see what is in there.